# generating cloud endpoint library falied

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Been working on this for hours and now its failing to generate my endpoint library. I generated an endpoint class for my entity class which is defined in the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities.  However generating the endpoint library fails with the exception below.

```
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Wed Mar 20 13:49:16 CDT 2013
Unexpected Exception

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:96)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:364)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 5 in method com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.Note.___jdo$loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; at offset 0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:620)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:408)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.classWithCreators(BasicClassIntrospector.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:919)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.JacksonBeanPropertyProvider.getProperties(JacksonBeanPropertyProvider.java:29)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addBeanProperties(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:686)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addBeanTypeToSchema(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:657)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addTypeToSchema(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:642)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addTypeToNode(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:744)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertMethodResponseType(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:541)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertMethodResponse(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:527)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertApiMethod(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:408)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertApiMethods(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:380)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertApiMethods(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:367)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfigObjects(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:251)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfig(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:185)
    ... 41 more
Root exception:
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 5 in method com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.Note.___jdo$loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; at offset 0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:620)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:408)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.classWithCreators(BasicClassIntrospector.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:919)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.JacksonBeanPropertyProvider.getProperties(JacksonBeanPropertyProvider.java:29)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addBeanProperties(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:686)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addBeanTypeToSchema(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:657)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addTypeToSchema(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:642)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.addTypeToNode(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:744)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertMethodResponseType(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:541)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertMethodResponse(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:527)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertApiMethod(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:408)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertApiMethods(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:380)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.convertApiMethods(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:367)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfigObjects(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:251)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfig(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:96)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:364)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler version was wrong.  It should have been 1.6 instead of 1.7